# jquery datepicker - Conflict when two dates in same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker, jqmodal

I have a form with two date fields.  It's quite a big form, so I'll just show the relevant parts.

```
<input id="dateofassessment" name="dateofassessment"  readonly="readonly" class='datebox' />
<input id="LastIncident" name="LastIncident" readonly="readonly" class="datebox" />
```

( I should point out that "dateofassessment" is the first item in the form, and "LastIncident" is the last item )

I attach the datepicker object like this..

```
    $(".datebox").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false
        });
```

The "dateofassessment" input box works perfectly.  The calendar is shown OK, and clicking on a date fills in the "dateofassessment"field - Perfect!

However, the "LastIncident" box doesn't work so well.  Clicking on it displays the calendar OK.  However, selecting a date does not fill in the form.  In fact the calendar closes on the "LastIncident", and re-opens on the "dateofassessment" field as soon as I select a date.

I can't post the entire code as there's vast amounts of it, on an intranet site.  But hopefully I have posted the relevant parts.

FYI,The fact the fields are "readonly" doesn't make any difference.

Versions...
jQuery v1.5.1
Datepicker 1.8.9

Comment: Current jQuery Release: v1.6.2 | Current jQuery UI Release: v1.8.14. Please updated the libraries and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: Good thinking.  I've now updated to latest versions, as suggested.  Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: Your code [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/wEWRr/), is there any chance you have a problem somewhere else in your code?

Comment: SOLUTION: I've looked outside the code above for a problem, and it appears to be a conflict with jqModal.  The form was in a modal div.  When I change this to be non-modal, the problem goes away.  Searching the net for jqModal and datapicker, people have reported problems with z-index, and I guess this could account for the unexplained behaviour of the calendar object moving from one form field to another.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's obviousely bug with datepicker. Insted of using

```
$(".datebox").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false
        });
```

Try

```
$("#dateofassessment").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false
        });

$("#LastIncident").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false
        });
```

I know it makes you repeat yourself which is bad but it could help to sort out the problem. Or you can try another datepicker. Or update this one the newer version

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ivan.  In fact, that's how I had originally coded it.  Unfortunately, it didn't work using this code either.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is located elsewhere, see this fiddle which works as expected : http://jsfiddle.net/AfmpL/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .setDefaults to make all datepickers behave the same (I have mine in my masterpage, not even in OnDocumentReady, because I want it run before OnDocumentReady functions).

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/Program/Images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: ""
})
```

And therefore, you won't have to repeat yourself nearly as much.

```
$("#dateofassessment").datepicker();
$("#LastIncident").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
});

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );   
});
```

Then use the following form fields:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="fecha_ingreso" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="fecha_ingreso2" />
```